# using jtable values in a mysql select statement in the where clause

Tags: mysql, select, jtable

i am  currently working on a project that has led me to need to use the values from a JTable in a select statement in the where clause to be precise. can someone help me with this endeavor. my aim is to use each value at a time in the query and for it to iterate through the entire column and display the results in another JTable,so far i keep getting a single row as a result and its from the last row so i suspect it is iterating through the column but showing the result-set for the last value only, this is what i have so far`

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
          try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jurassic","root","1234");
    int rows=jTable1.getRowCount();
    for(int row = 0; row<rows; row++)
    {   
     Object jambo = ( Object)jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0);
     String queryco = "select distinct fname from cosplay where jambo = '" + jambo + "'";
     pst = conn.prepareStatement(queryco);
     rs=pst.executeQuery(); 
     table3.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); 
      }
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successful Save");
  }
  catch(Exception e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
  }
    }                           `
```

Comment: `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)` <-- we need to see what this is doing.

Comment: it is printing the results into the next jtable which is giving me the fname from the last value in the column jambo only

Comment: I don't see a problem actually.  You should try to give a reproducible example so that others may help you.

Comment: i am using netbeans so the jtables are autogenerated so what you see here is the only customized code. the mysql table is just a basic table with just two columns, one for jambo and fname and am using the select statement to print the values from the mysql table in the second jtable using the values  in the first jtable column jambo, there is not much and the jtables are just plain jtables without any customization whatsoever

Comment: hey can someone please help me here